# Acrescentar juros por parcela com BigDecimal?

Tags: java, matemática

Estou criando um sistema onde preciso calcular os juros e acrescentar as parcelas de um financiamento. Para isso, estou usando `BigDecimal` e não estou conseguindo realizar a operação matemática seguindo a fórmula de cálculos de prestação. Como fazer isso?

Estou tentando assim:

```
private void calcular(){
        /**
         * formula
         * PMT = PV. i
         *          ----
         *          1 - (1 + i)^-n
         * 
         */
        BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);
        BigDecimal pmt = new BigDecimal(0);
        BigDecimal valorVeiculo = ValorBigDecimal.getValor(txtParcela.getText()); 
        Integer parcela = Integer.parseInt(txtParcela.getText());
        BigDecimal entrada = valorEntrada();
        BigDecimal juros = ValorBigDecimal.getValor(txtJuros.getText()).divide(new BigDecimal(100));

        //valor do veiculo - valor entrada
        total = total.add(valorVeiculo).subtract(entrada);

        //calcula prestacao
        pmt = pmt.add(total).multiply(juros.divide(new BigDecimal(1).subtract(new BigDecimal(1).add(juros).pow(parcela))));
        pmt = pmt.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        System.out.println(pmt);


    }
```

**Tela**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E qual é sua dúvida?

Comment: @bigown a dúvida eh que acredito que eu esteja fazendo errado pois não consigo chegar ao resultado. Por isso perguntei como fazer ?

Comment: Fernando, você tem o calculo matemático?

Comment: Essa é a formula : PMT = PV. i  / 1 - (1 + i)^-n ?

Comment: O que é PMT, PV, i, e n? Tente colocar na sua pergunta uma legenda!

Comment: @seamusd pelo que pesquisei existe uma formula pra isso, que eh que deixei enunciado no metodo `calcular()`, é ela que estou tentando fazer. Tentei seguir esse video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6V2QOv1qLE

Comment: Fernando, edite a pergunta e informe que precisa fazer isso utilizando BIgDecimal, pois utilizando primitivos, pode ter alguns problemas com precisão. Assim, você deixa evidente a necessidade do BigDecimal.

Comment: @diegofm eu acho uma boa dica, ainda que se é prestação, envolve dinheiro, está implícito que não pode ser *double*, e no código dele já mostrava que era `BigDecimal` desde o princípio. O pessoal precisa ler a pergunta antes de responder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvido. 
Segui 2 formulas para chegar ao resultado a primeira formula `PMT = PV * i / 1 - (1 + i)^-n` e a segunda formula `PMT = PV / (1 + i)^n - 1 / (1 + i)^n * i`. Com a primeira formula não consegui fazer funcionar, soh tive sucesso usando a segunda formula que ficou como abaixo.

```
private void calcular(){
        /**
         * formulas
         * F1 -> PMT = PV * i / 1 - (1 + i)^-n (nao funciona)       
         * F2 -> PMT = PV / (1 + i)^n - 1 / (1 + i)^n * i (funciona 100%)
         */
        BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);
        BigDecimal diferenca = new BigDecimal(0);
        BigDecimal pv = ValorBigDecimal.getValor(txtValorVeiculo.getText());
        BigDecimal juros = ValorBigDecimal.getValor(txtJuros.getText()).divide(new BigDecimal(100));
        BigDecimal entrada = getValorEntrada();
        Integer parcelas = Integer.parseInt(txtParcela.getText());
        BigDecimal taxa = new BigDecimal(0);
        BigDecimal t1 = new BigDecimal(0);
        BigDecimal t2 = new BigDecimal(0);

        //calcula diferenca entre valor do veiculo e a entrada        
        diferenca = diferenca.add(pv).subtract(entrada);
        //(1 + i)^n - 1 
        t1 = BigDecimal.ONE.add(juros).pow(parcelas).subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
        //(1 + i)^n * i
        t2 = BigDecimal.ONE.add(juros).pow(parcelas).multiply(juros);
        //(1 + i)^n - 1 / (1 + i)^n * i -> t1 / t2
        taxa = t1.divide(t2, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        total = diferenca.divide(taxa, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        System.out.println(t1);
        System.out.println(t2);
        System.out.println(taxa);
        System.out.println(total);        

    }
```

Comment: Você pode usar `BigDecimal.ZERO` ao invés de `new BigDecimal(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

Bem, eu fiz esta classe para resolver o seu problema:

```
public final class PrecoComJuros {
    private final BigDecimal valorBase;
    private final BigDecimal valorParcelado; // pv
    private final BigDecimal entrada;
    private final int numeroParcelas;
    private final BigDecimal taxaJuros;
    private final BigDecimal valorParcela;
    private final BigDecimal valorTotal; // pmt
    private final BigDecimal valorJuros;

    public PrecoComJuros(BigDecimal valorBase, BigDecimal entrada, int numeroParcelas, BigDecimal taxaJuros) {
        if (numeroParcelas <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (taxaJuros.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.valorBase = valorBase;
        this.entrada = entrada;
        this.numeroParcelas = numeroParcelas;
        this.taxaJuros = taxaJuros;
        BigDecimal juros = taxaJuros.divide(CEM); // i
        this.valorParcelado = valorBase.subtract(entrada);
        if (taxaJuros.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
            this.valorParcela = valorParcelado.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(numeroParcelas), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        } else {
            BigDecimal potencia = juros.add(BigDecimal.ONE).pow(numeroParcelas);
            BigDecimal denominador = BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE.divide(potencia, 20, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
            this.valorParcela = valorParcelado.multiply(juros).divide(denominador, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        }
        this.valorJuros = valorParcela.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(numeroParcelas));
        this.valorTotal = entrada.add(valorJuros);
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorBase() {
        return valorBase;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorParcelado() {
        return valorParcelado;
    }

    public BigDecimal getEntrada() {
        return entrada;
    }

    public int getNumeroParcelas() {
        return numeroParcelas;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTaxaJuros() {
        return taxaJuros;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorParcela() {
        return valorParcela;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorTotal() {
        return valorTotal;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorJuros() {
        return valorJuros;
    }
}
```

Eis aqui o teste dela:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(" : : ".split(":")));
    PrecoComJuros p = new PrecoComJuros(BigDecimal.valueOf(30_000), BigDecimal.valueOf(10_000), 24, BigDecimal.valueOf(5));
    System.out.println("Valor da parcela: " + p.getValorParcela());
    System.out.println("Juros total: " + p.getValorJuros());
    System.out.println("Valor total: " + p.getValorTotal());
}
```

Algumas observações sobre a implementação:

- Passar um expoente negativo para o método `pow` causa uma exceção. A solução para isso é notar que [image: a^(-b) = 1 / (a^b)], e portanto podemos eliminar a necessidade de utilizar-se um expoente negativo.
- Há um tratamento especial para o caso de a taxa de juros ser zero. Se não houvesse tal tratamento, uma divisão por zero ocorreria.
- Valores com números de parcelas igual a zero ou negativos ou com taxas de juros negativas são rejeitados.
- O valor da parcela é calculado com precisão de centavos (2 dígitos após a vírgula). Cálculos intermediários, no entanto usam até 20 casas depois da vírgula.

Comment: Muito boa resposta! +1 mais que merecido :)